# Where's this swanky house and vineyard near a mountain?

Tags: identify-this

The screencaps beneath are from [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/ffYZfG1AYgc), which itself is from the 2006 movie *Blood Diamond*. Jennifer Connelly (who starred in it) once remarked that it was filmed in South Africa and Mozambique.

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That's the Buitenverwachting vineyard, in Cape Town.

Source: http://travelandtourism.capetown/2015/02/23/beyond-expectation/

> One of the ‘wow’ pieces of information about this estate is that some of the scenes of ‘Blood Diamonds’ starring Leonardo di Caprio were shot here.